# Why do 2 elements of 50% not fit in the same row

Tags: css

### Question

If both `<li>` are `50%`, why won't they be side by side?

### Code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/) on jsfiddle.

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>left</li>
    <li>right</li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: gray;
    background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.83);
}
```

Comment: Because of `padding, border and white space` between the `inline-block` elements. I removed all of them in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/11/) (notice there's no space between the `li` elements).

Comment: However, you can use [box-sizing: border-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) to use the `padding and border` values - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/13/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because by default, `margin` `padding` and `border` are counted outside the element and not inside. So `padding` of `3px` + `border` of `1px` will be added to `50%` on all the sides.

Also am not sure whether you are resetting browser default `margin` and `padding` of the elements, if you aren't than do it. You can either use universal selector which some oppose as it hits performance by few bits, like

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Or if you want to reset in a lenient way than you can use [CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

[image]

So inorder to count the `padding` and `border` inside, you will have to use `box-sizing` property with a value of `border-box`.

Also you are using `inline-block` which will leave a `margin` / whitespace whatever you call of merely `4px` so make all the `li` in one line. OR what you can do is, you can [**`float`**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/10/) your elements to the `left`, so that you don't have to make all the `li` in one line in your source document.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/8/)

---

Just make sure you `clear` your floating elements if you are going with the `float` solution.

Answer (score 3):

**First problem:** With the `display:inline-block` property, there is a `white-space` betwen elements. This make the  `li` elments 100% + `white-space` is more than 100% so they can't fit on same line better use `float:left` for your issue

**Second problem:** You give a 3px border which makes your `li` elements more than 50% wide you could use the property `box-sizing:border-box;` which would make your borders inside the `li` elements

CSS:

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: gray;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: rgb(216, 216, 216);
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid rgba(179, 179, 179, 0.83);
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/12/)

Answer (score 1):

It is because the `<li>` elements have a padding. You have to remove the padding or decrease the width.

For example,

```
width: 48%; 
padding: 2%
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the padding.  Wash element is 50% + 3px wide.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is a simple problem

looks like you want a padding of

3px per `<li>`  you have 2 then you need 6px extras
and you have broder of 1px ( you have 2 borders per li) that means that you have 4px extras.

That means that you need 10 px extras

You just need to change this line

```
width: calc(50% - 10px);
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/L5DbR/14/

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned `display: inline-block;` adds space between blocks.

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 0; /*This is a hack for inline-block to not add space between blocks*/
}
```

The above code is a hack to make the "space" between `<li>` elements become zero. Source: CSS Tricks - https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qcc0prea/)